# An unhandled lowlevel error occurred

Tags: mysql, passenger, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails is asking me to look at the application log, which may have details.

Which directory do I look for the log?  Please advise.  Thank you.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Answer updated see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112804/an-unhandled-lowlevel-error-occurred-the-application-logs-may-have-details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May be you are running production mode without setting secret key**
if not refer to your server console for more details.
Sometiime it is due to secret key has not been set for production mode.

**How to generate secret key**
run command `rake secret` in terminal. Then you will see secret key like this:

```
a0bf18e677f3e49cebc6c8edad3e7af92504c7114777e48546ee46e4ece66c2b7de3f6beafa083a26a342146d096d2e051fb80836efee246ea8ca2dae7d28f41
```

Copy it and paste in secret key location as shown below.

If so set secret key in config/secret.yml file:

```
development:
 secret_key_base: 81f8d43274fcf0021b6f0dda479ab2983e691b3e9ca9a15096197ba48b43cae92f4526cc4114699fc36f28a537cfa17d8d16f2a69c059f385b7845a9299db9fa

test:
 secret_key_base: 9091e24ff70de567787175551ece68b0de6b793964d74f4d5d59b09f361640a738b076299f4f27ad09ecdc4c2ff6e4199e7a081b6dcc0f41c1017a829174e09d

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
 secret_key_base:  paste your key here.
```

Comment: Thank you, Pradeep, for your response.  I'm new to rails. Would you guide me to set secret key for production.

Comment: Thanks again, Pradeep.  As you mentioned, I have not set up production mode properly.  I am reading more documentation on that.