# Rails: An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, puma

I made this on my server:

```
deploy@ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01:~/applications/spa_backend/current$ bundle exec rake secret
4b921910**
deploy@ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01:~/applications/spa_backend/current$ export SECRET_KEY_BASE=4b921910**
deploy@ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01:~/applications/spa_backend/current$ irb
irb(main):001:0> ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
=> "4b921910**"
```

And when I try open link with my app, I see this:

`An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.`

puma_error.log:

```
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/deploy/applications/spa_backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:513:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/home/deploy/applications/spa_backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
```

**secrets.yml:**

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

**UPD.** I changed `<%= ENV["secret_key_base"] %>` -> `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>` but it didn't help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112804/an-unhandled-lowlevel-error-occurred-the-application-logs-may-have-details)

Answer (score 9):

In your `secrets.yml`, your environment variable key needs to be capitalized. Calling `ENV['secret_key_base']` is returning `nil`.

Modify your `secrets.yml` like below:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to produce the 'secret_key_base' first.

```
bundle exec rake secret
```

The code above will produce the necessary key. 
Copy it and replace <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %> with it.

Here is the original post:

[An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112804/an-unhandled-lowlevel-error-occurred-the-application-logs-may-have-details)

Answer (score -7):

If you use **GitHub**, check your `.gitignore` file. `.gitignore` template for Rails application includes `config/secrets.yml` and error resolves by commenting out the line.

Comment: Do not do this.  Secrets are not supposed to be added to version control for a reason.