# An unhandled lowlevel error occurred after I added Devise secre key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, devise

I typically make updates to my production Ruby on Rails application and today I updated some security vulnerabilities with gem files, pushed them to my Github repo and then did a git push heroku master and received the following errors:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
remote:
remote:          config.secret_key = '<hash>'
remote:
remote:        Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key....
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
```

Not sure if there is a connection between actionview -v 5.1.6.2 that I recently updated to and this error, but I went ahead and added that `config.secret_key = ...` and then committed it and pushed to my repo and then did the `git push heroku master` and now I get this:

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

Heroku logs say:

```
 #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

But I have this in my `config/secrets.yml`:

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the unencrypted secrets file.
# Instead, either read values from the environment.
# Or, use `bin/rails secrets:setup` to configure encrypted secrets
# and move the `production:` environment over there.

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Do application logs indeed have details?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112804/an-unhandled-lowlevel-error-occurred-the-application-logs-may-have-details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to go with what Heroku was suggesting of setting the Devise secret key in my `devise.rb` file and instead went over to `application.rb` file and added the following line of code:

`config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]`

I had forgotten that Heroku already has my secret key base set, so after adding this line of code to `application.rb` file and committing the changes to my Github repo, I ran a `git push heroku master` and then ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and my production RoR site is up and running again, good as new.

This solution was better at avoiding having any secret key in my `devise.rb` file which would not be a good idea from a security standpoint.